# Convert a int32 value into a fixed pt, but the fixed pt data type is stored as a char

Tags: matlab, fixed-point

I have a value that is 32 bits long that I get from a `.bin` file. Once I extract this value, I want to convert it into it's proper data type which is stored in my MATLAB workspace as a char. For example, the char could be `'fixdt(0,2,0)'` or `'uint32'` or `'fixdt(1,23,4)'`, etc.

How can I do this? Should I try and convert it in `fread()` or should I first extract the individual bits and then use `fi()` in some way?

Comment: doesnt matter really. You will just need a switch-case statement though, to change your casting code depending on your desired type. Maybe you need some regexp (or string parsing) to detect the parameters of `fixdt`, but otherwise you should be good to just try this. Anything stopping you from giving it a try?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What do you mean by a "switch-case statement"? I can use string parsing to detect the parameters of `fixdt`, however, some of the values I need to do this for aren't expressed as `fixdt`, they are expressed as `uint8` for example. This makes string parsing almost impossible in my opinion. 

From what I've found online I can do this: `mydata = fread(fid,'uint8=>uint16')`, but the the output data type can't handle generic precisions like `fixdt(1,4,3)`

Comment: a `switch-case` is a fundamental structure of programming, like an `if` or a `for`. Check it out, its what you want. https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html